# Java regex plus at the beginning is optional

Tags: java, regex

I would like to write Java regex where plus at the beginning is optional

I try this but not working correctly

```
[+]+[0-9]{3,}
```

so that +123 and 123 is valid

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `+` means match the preceding token one or more time. Use `?` for zero or one time which means optional :) [*Further reading*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 2):

As Hamza commented below, use `[+]?[0-9]{3,}`. A question mark means one or none of the previous, which in this case means one or no + before the three numbers.